# List of NotChargingReason Codes from terminal command ioreg

Tags: terminal, battery, charging, charger, system-information

Does anyone know the descriptions of the NotChargingReason code from the ioreg command.

For example, when I type this command:

```
ioreg -l -w0 | grep 'ChargerData'
```

I get the following output:

```
 "ChargerData" = {"ChargingCurrent"=0,"NotChargingReason"=23,"ChargingVoltage"=13048,"VacVoltageLimit"=4350}
```

I've seen different code numbers for the NotChargingReason variable besides 23. I've also seen 6, 4 and 1... I would just like to know if there is a text description of these codes somewhere?

I have tried googling with no luck... and mind you, I'm not your typical googler. I'm a programmer who knows how to use the advanced google features.